# Celery+Django -- Poll task for state and report success or failure using Django messages framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, celery

In my Django project that uses Celery (among a number of other things), I have a Celery task that will upload a file to a database in the background. I use polling to keep track of the upload progress and display a progress bar for uploading. Here are some snippets that detail the upload process:

views.py:

```
from .tasks import upload_task
...

upload_task.delay(datapoints, user, description) # datapoints is a list of dictionaries, user and description are simple strings
```

tasks.py:

```
from taskman.celery import app, DBTask # taskman is the name of the Django app that has celery.py
from celery import task, current_task

@task(base=DBTask)
def upload_task(datapoints, user, description):
    from utils.db.databaseinserter import insertIntoDatabase
    for count in insertIntoDatabase(datapoints, user, description):
        percent_completion = int(100 * (float(count) / float(len(datapoints))))
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'percent':percent_completion})
```

databaseinserter.py:

```
def insertIntoDatabase(datapoints, user, description):
    # iterate through the datapoints and upload them one by one
    # at the end of an iteration, yield the number of datapoints completed so far
```

The uploading code all works well, and the progress bar also works properly. However, I'm not sure how to send a Django message that tells the user that the upload is complete (or, in the event of an error, send a Django message informing the user of the error). When the upload begins, I do this in views.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...

messages.info(request, "Upload is in progress")
```

And I want to do something like this when an upload is successful:

```
messages.info(request, "Upload successful!")
```

I can't do that in views.py since the Celery task is fire and forget. Is there a way to do this in celery.py? In my `DBTask` class in celery.py I have `on_success` and `on_failure` defined, so would I be able to send Django messages from there?

Also, while my polling technically works, it's not currently ideal. The way the polling works currently is that it will endlessly check for a task regardless of whether one is in progress or not. It quickly floods the server console logs and I can imagine has a negative impact on performance overall. I'm pretty new to writing polling code so I'm not entirely sure of best practices and such as well as how to only poll when I need to. What is the best way to deal with the constant polling and the clogging of the server logs? Below is my code for polling.

views.py:

```
def poll_state(request):
    data = 'Failure'
    if request.is_ajax():
        if 'task_id' in request.POST.keys() and request.POST['task_id']:
            task_id = request.POST['task_id']
            task = AsyncResult(task_id)
            data = task.result or task.state
            if data == 'SUCCESS' or data == 'FAILURE': # not sure what to do here; what I want is to exit the function early if the current task is already completed
                return HttpResponse({}, content_type='application/json')
        else:
            data ='No task_id in the request'
            logger.info('No task_id in the request')
    else:
        data = 'Not an ajax request'
        logger.info('Not an ajax request')

    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

And the corresponding jQuery code:

```
{% if task_id %}
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var PollState = function(task_id) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "poll_state",
                type: "POST",
                data: "task_id=" + task_id,
            }).done(function(task) {
                if (task.percent) {
                    jQuery('.bar').css({'width': task.percent + '%'});
                    jQuery('.bar').html(task.percent + '%');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('.status').html(task);
                };
                PollState(task_id);
            });
        }
        PollState('{{ task_id }}');
    })
{% endif %}
```

(These last two snippets come largely from previous StackOverflow questions on Django+Celery progress bars.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Josh K for the tip on using `setTimeout`. Unfortunately I could never figure out the middleware approach, so instead I'm going with a simpler approach of sending an HttpResponse in `poll_state` like so:

```
if data == "SUCCESS":
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"message":"Upload successful!", "state":"SUCCESS"}, content_type='application/json'))
elif data == "FAILURE":
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"message":"Error in upload", "state":"FAILURE"}, content_type='application/json'))
```

The intent is to simply render a success or error message based on the JSON received. There are new problems now but those are for a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to reduce logging and overhead is to put a timeout on your next `PollState` call. The way your function is written right now it immediately polls again. Something simple like:

```
setTimeout(function () { PollState(task_id); }, 5000);
```

This will drastically reduce your logging issue and overhead.

---

Regarding your Django messaging question you'd need to pull those completed tasks out with some sort of processing. One way to do it is a `Notification` model—or similar—which you can then add a piece of middleware to fetch unread notifications and inject them into the messages framework.

Comment: I've never written my own middleware for a Django project so I'm a little unsure of how to go about this. At a high level I know that I want to store a completion message in redis (the broker and backend for celery that I'm using) and then pop unread messages and display completion messages on the web page, but I'm a little lost on how to write that. Could you possibly write some rough example code to point me in the right direction?